# How to move sidebar when scrolling

Tags: wordpress

I have a sidebar calling "Related Reviews" here https://www.reclinerland.com/recliners/
I'm trying to make it movable with the scroll, but when the page is scrolled to the bottom and I click the arrow "go to the top" screen goes up but the sidebar keeps staying at the bottom.

Comment: The Sidebar section "text-widget" is been fixed while scrolling down. There might be any JS code is written to put these code. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you are using ReHub Theme, please find that how the sidebar can be sticky. You can get help from this [URL](http://rehubdocs.wpsoul.com/docs/rehub-theme/basic-settings/custom-sidebar-and-widgets/)